# How to work with parameters in telegraf in commands

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

**Hey guys I want to use parameters in my bot **

For example I send
/ping hello 5
`ctx.reply(You want me to ping hello 5 times)`

In the above code /ping is the command while hello and 5 are parameters so I can access them in my codes

In

`bot.command('ping')`

I don't think it works so I need help to work with parameters

Answer (score 7):

You should parse ctx.update.message.text - it is the full command with other text. For example, `ctx.update.message.text.split(' ')` returns array of arguments with a command in 0 place